# Chrome Extension with JavaScript, for changing CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

as many others, I've started to do a Chrome Extension, which should change the CSS of a specific page.
I've read the other threads, but what I want to do is a bit more complicated than the other.
On the webpage I would like to change the style, there's a select list, with one, or more options.

Basically this looks like the following:
`<select id="users"><option value="123">Username</option></select>`
The '123' is the user's ID, unique for everyone.

So what I would like to do, is to insert the CSS file, based on the user ID.
So I'd like to insert the new CSS like:

//mysite/myfolder/cssfiles/ #userID# .css

My problem is that the page I'd like to customize is not mine, so  I can't do this on the server-side, but I'd like to do an Extension for my co-workers to feel a bit unique every time they look at the webpage.

In the manifest.json file, the following content_script runs now:

```
"content_scripts": [
{
"js": ["myscript.js"]
}
]
```

and my myscript.js is the following:

```
var user = document.getElementById("users");
var id = user.options[user.selectedIndex].value;
var name = user.options[user.selectedIndex].text;
var showinfo = alert("Userid: " + id + "\nUsername: " + name);
```

When the page loads, the alert shows the data correctly, but I haven't figured out yet how could I use them to insert my CSS.

I've also put next to the "js": part for testing purposes the "css": ["mystyle.css"] but this is one pre-definied style, and doesn't depends on the selected user, however it makes the page looks like how I wanted and have written it in the CSS.

Comment: Is there one single user ID you want CSS for? or is the user ID dynamic based on a setting/person using the extension?

Comment: It's dynamic, to make the things more complicated..

Comment: Then `//mysite/myfolder/cssfiles/ #userID# .css` won't work because  you'd have to create a css file for every single user.

Comment: But if I dont't have a precreated one, the default should be loaded.

I shouldn't complicate it so badly, should I..?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do this would be something like:

```
var id = window.prompt("Enter your id","default");
var filepath = id + ".css";
chrome.tabs.insertCSS(tabId,{file:filepath});
```

Note that this requires the tabs permission in your manifest.